# Why is my else block not executing in my OnClickListener in java android studio

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

i created a feature that lets my app users favorite shops. now if a user already favorited a shop and clicks on the button again it should delete the record from the firestore database.

my code works only if there is a match to the query and the task is successful, but doesnt execute my `else` part of the code. why is that?

and here isthe below code works fine when there is a match for the `query` and the `task is successful`, but when there isn't it doesnt execute the `else` part. anyone know why?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        Task ref = fStore.collection("Favorites")
           .whereEqualTo("shopID", SID).whereEqualTo("usersID", UID)
                      .get()
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                       @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                              document.getReference().delete();
                                        }
                   } else {
      Map<String, Object> fav = new HashMap<>();
    
                         

         fav.put("shopID", SID);
         fav.put("usersID", UID);
         fav.put("ShopHeaderImg", sHI);
         fav.put("ShopProfileImg", sPI);
         fav.put("address", sA);
         fav.put("costEst", sCost);
         fav.put("country", sC);
         fav.put("latitude", sLat);
         fav.put("location", sL);
         fav.put("name", sN);
         fav.put("numTables", sNumTable);
         fav.put("ratings", sR);
         fav.put("summary", sSummary);
         fav.put("timing", sT);
    
    
                                      
      fStore.collection("Favorites").add(fav)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                       @Override
     public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
   Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                          

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what `task.isSuccessful()` means.  That method will return true if there were no errors during the execution of the query.  A query that returns no documents isn't an error.  That situation is perfectly normal, and considered successful. An error only happens when you try to execute a query that Firestore can't actually run.

If you want to check if a query returned no documents, you should look at the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) contained in the task results.  It has a method [isEmpty()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#isEmpty()) that will tell you if there are documents.

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
        if (querySnapshot.isEmpty()) {
            // put code here to deal with no documents in the result
        }
        else {
            // put code here to deal with documents present in the result
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for clarifying, ive been working for two hours on this now, there was no way i would understand this. thank you!!! it works perfectly now.